# There is a function in Powershell to ConvertTo-Webappliction, is there a way to do this in Python?

Tags: python, web-applications, powershell

The problem with PowerShell scripts is that they have to be signed to run on other computers. Python doesn't, it just has to be installed. Is there a way to do implement [ConvertTo-WebApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807827.aspx) using Python?

PS Command:

```
ConvertTo-WebApplication "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\name\Name"
```

Comment: Are you entirely opposed to [setting a different ExecutionPolicy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx) for PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be accomplished with [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#Description_of_Pexpect).